# Problem with removing a specifc object of a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem for removing a specific element in a list.

I have used splice who is supposed to cut the element at a certain point but it always remove the last element.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <h3>Steam</h3>
        <v-btn class="mx-2" fab dark color="purple" @click="addCardSteam">
          <v-icon dark>mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <h3>Map 2D et 3D</h3>
        <v-btn class="mx-2" fab dark color="cyan" @click="addCardMaps">
          <v-icon dark>mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <h3>Youtube</h3>
        <v-btn class="mx-2" fab dark color="red" @click="addCardYT">
          <v-icon dark>mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <YTCard v-for="(card, index) in Youtube"
        v-bind:key="index"
        v-model="card.deleted"
        @input="UpdateYT"></YTCard>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import YTCard from './YoutubeCard'

export default {
  data: () => ({
    Steam: [],
    Maps: [],
    Youtube: [],
    YT: 0
  }),
  methods: {
    UpdateYT: function () {
      console.log('Youtube => ', this.Youtube)
      this.Youtube = this.Youtube.filter(yt => !yt.deleted)
    },
    addCardYT: function (num) {
      this.YT = this.YT + 1
      this.Youtube.push({deleted: false, num: this.YT})
    },
    addCardMaps: function () {
      this.Maps.push({deleted: false})
    },
    addCardSteam: function () {
      this.Steam.push({deleted: false})
    }
  },
  components: {
    YTCard
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

I have tried different ways but it always destroys the last element.

Does someone has an explanation or an idea.

I have edited the Question i hope it make it clearier.

Comment: The Hello part has been removed

Comment: Why do you need `i--` you a re checking against the length of the array which should change with a splice?

Comment: I have saw this way on https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/ but before i was using 
`for (let i = 0; i < this.Youtube.length; i++) {
        console.log('i = ', i)
        console.log(this.Youtube[i].deleted)
        if (this.Youtube[i].deleted === true) {
          console.log('i = ', i)
          this.Youtube.splice(i, 1)
        }
      }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over an array by `i` as index, when you're potentially changing the array as you're iterating, is definitely going to give you bugs

What about something like this?:

```js
var RandomClass = {
  // this is how i update
  Youtube: [],

  UpdateYT: function () {
      // console.log('Youtube => ', this.Youtube)
      this.Youtube = this.Youtube.filter(yt => !yt.deleted);
  },

  addCardYT: function (num) {
    this.Youtube.push({deleted: false, num:num})
  },
}

RandomClass.addCardYT(1);
RandomClass.addCardYT(2);
console.log(RandomClass.Youtube);
RandomClass.Youtube[0].deleted = true;
RandomClass.UpdateYT();
console.log(RandomClass.Youtube);
```

[edit]

If you insisted on wanting to iterate over `i` and delete them as they come up, what you should do is start at the end of the array and work your way backwards.

Comment: I have tried your method but it still remove the last element

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. You haven't really given me much to work with there

Comment: I have edited the question i hope it make my problem easier to understand. Sorry. @TKol

Comment: Your answers were great I just had a problem with my card

Answer (score 0):

```
const youtube = [
    { id: 1, deleted: false },
    { id: 2, deleted: true },
    { id: 3, deleted: false },
    { id: 4, deleted: true },
    { id: 5, deleted: true },
    { id: 6, deleted: false },
];

console.log('Initial', youtube);

const update = () => {
    let i = youtube.length - 1
    while (i != 0) {
        if (youtube[i].deleted) youtube.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}

update();

console.log('Updated', youtube);
```

**Edit:** TKoL was right; iterating over an array like that can create bugs if two consecutive elements need to be removed. Iterating over it backwards should work just fine.

Comment: The bug with iterating over `i` like this is that if two consecutive values need removing, then you'll probably only remove one of them

Comment: Iterate backwards over an array in this case, if you want to. Removing an item at the end of an array doesn't affect the index of an item at the beginning of the array, but the reverse isn't true.

Comment: @TKoL I have tried both but i still have the same problem. I have reedited it again and i still have the problem